# can't access morphOne relationship

Tags: laravel

I am having a problem accessing morphOne relationship

In my controller I have

```
    $post = Post::with('content')->where('id', 1)->get();
    dd($post);
```

this gives

[image]

This is setup of my classes:

Post.php

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use Contentable;
```

Contentable.php

```
trait Contentable {

    public function content()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Content::class, 'contentable');
    }
```

Content.php

```
class Content extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'content';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

If in controller I do this:

```
dd($post->content());
```

I get Method content does not exist.

or

```
dd($post->content);
```

I get Property [content] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Are they in the same namespace?

Comment: yes they are, I have solved it, I needed to call first() instead of get()